# how to implement viewpager with same fragments but with large number of count?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

This is my Adapter just for test run,
Now I want to change getItem() so that it can support large number of items.
like 30(and this number changes in different situation).
I have the imageSet array ready.
pls help.

private class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

```
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                fragment = new Image();
                bundle.putString("ImageId", imageSet[position]);
                bundle.putString("ImageName","asd");
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Image();
                bundle.putString("ImageId", imageSet[position]);
                bundle.putString("ImageName","asd");
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Image();
                bundle.putString("ImageId", imageSet[position]);
                bundle.putString("ImageName","asd");
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new Image();
                bundle.putString("ImageId", imageSet[position]);
                bundle.putString("ImageName","asd");
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageSet.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of a FragementPagerAdapter, as it will implement a more efficient caching and instance creation strategy.

```
private class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

  public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new Image();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("ImageId", imageSet[position]);
    bundle.putString("ImageName","asd");
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return imageSet.length;
  }
}
```